# TeamViewer ctrl-alt doesn't work

Tags: teamviewer

I connect from Ubuntu 13.04 (Gnome) to Windows 7 through TeamViewer

- TeamViewer Windows - 8.0.19617
- TeamViewer Ubuntu  - 8.0.17.147

The 'Send Key' combination option in TeamViewer is enabled.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd> keys don't work. If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>, I can select the open windows in Ubuntu, but not in Windows 7 on remote.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 6):

If you use "Show position of pointer when the Control key is pressed" (mouse and touchpad settings) try to disable it. It did the trick for me...

Comment: In windows you mean?

Comment: If you are running Ubuntu, go to "Preferences > Mouse & Touchpad" and turn OFF "Show position of pointer when the Control key is pressed". This fixed it for me and I can now copy/paste remotely to Windows.

Comment: Oh f**k me, Thanks a lot! It works for me, AND, IT FIXED "Can't use Ctrl+C to copy file name in caja file manager, when Ctrl is presssed, file name edit mode is automatically closed" issue, it bothered me for a loooooong time

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you might have issues if you are using [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/). <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>ing worked until I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to switch desktops. Then keyboard shortcuts started failing. I think the problem has to do with other programs listening to system-wide keystrokes, so go through your programs to see which one might be causing the issue.