# Send Super and Ctrl/Alt keys from Ubuntu host to Ubuntu client

Tags: teamviewer

Similarly to [this Ask Ubuntu user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325194/teamviewer-ctrl-alt-doesnt-work), I'm having trouble getting TeamViewer 10 (Wine 1.6) to send keys to my host.

The difference is, I'm both hosting *and* have a client on Linux Mint 17 (based on Ubuntu 14.04).

None of the <kbd>Super</kbd> keys send (for window snapping etc.), nor do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> combinations (for switching workspaces etc.)

Has anybody ever had this working?